# UILocalNotification every 15 Minutes, but not at night (after 10pm)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I want to fire an UILocalNotification every 15 minutes. That is no problem:

```
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    notification.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:15];
    notification.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;



    notification.alertBody = NSLocalizedString(@"Alert", @"");
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

But I would like to do that only between 8am and 10pm. How can I handle that?

Comment: You will need to schedule notification for each time and make them the `repeatInterval` equal to `NSCalendarUnitDay`. So you need one for 8:00, 8:15, 8:30 etc... But keep in mind that iOS is limited to max 64 notification per app. If you add new one old one might be removed.

Comment: What about making an if statement asking if the nsdate is between 8am-10pm?

Comment: @JakobMikkelsen You need to schedule the notifications when the app is running, since iOS don't always run in the background you can not use an if statement.

Comment: which annoying app will that be? just for avoiding to download it ever...

Comment: @rckoenes ofcourse.. but i thought that was self explaining.. :P

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `repeaInterval`, you probably think of repeat the notification every 15 min, but you have a problem if you want to skip hours.
You could also schedule all notifications for one day (add one for 7:00am, 7:15am, 7:30am, etc) and repeat them for an interval of 1 day. If you want 4 notifications per hour, from 7am to 10pm that makes 60 notifications (which is under the max 64).